# In Django: specific database table for listing items

Tags: python, django

In Django, most of the fields I want in my list view are linked through a foreign key:

```
class MyUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display      = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', )
    def first_name(self, obj):
        return obj.dragonuser.first_name
    def last_name(self, obj):
        return obj.dragonuser.last_name
    def email(self, obj):
        return obj.dragonuser.email

    first_name.short_description = 'First name'
    last_name.short_description  = 'Last name'
    email.short_description      = 'Email address'
```

This works, but because Django never fetched any of these fields from the database, it can't sort them or use them for filtering. That's bad. So I made a view right into the database. I don't want to use it for creating or editing instances. I have custom forms for that. I would like to use that custom table for listing elements only. But I'm not sure where to add that code. In the admin definition? In the manager? Elsewhere?

I could make a custom method in the manager, but how would I tell the admin view to call that specific function?

By the time the method `changelist_view` has been called in the admin, the call to the database has already been made (based on what I could tell by examining the arguments passed to it):

```
def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
    from pprint import pprint
    pprint(dir(request))
    return super(BaseUserAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context)
```

So where should I tell Django to use another database table (really a view) only for the listing operation?

Comment: I think people may get tripped up by your use of "database view".

Comment: Edited title to fix that. Thanks @PaulDraper.

Comment: Show me an example of your view

Comment: can you override the ```get_queryset``` method in the manager to perform a query against the view (which I assume has your extended fields in addition the base model fields) rather than the actual model table. Maybe using .raw('sql to select from view?') ?

Comment: I'll look up how to do that. I' haven't had to use `get_queryset` so far in my project. Thanks, @mconlin.

Comment: Overloading `get_query_set` in the manager is not an option because there's no way of knowing if the current view is a list view within the manager. I'm still looking into it, though.

Comment: Could you override `get_queryset` (1.6, `queryset` for < 1.6) on the ModelAdmin?

Comment: I've tried changing the `get_changelist` but the `get_queryset` (I'm on 1.5). I'll try that next. Thanks, @jproffitt.